# How to store strings in database that can be in different encodings

Tags: sql-server, string, encoding, utf-8

I have an application that processes email and stores the subject / message body in a database.
This information is used to to preview the emails in a web appliciation before opening the email from disk in outlook.

Emails can be sent with different text-encodings.

To store the subject and body content into the database I feel I need to store the encoding used in the email and then I have 2 options:

- store them in binary form
- store them base64 encoded

(from: [Safely Store HTML in DB without affecting Character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332633/safely-store-html-in-db-without-affecting-character-encoding))

this because I fear I will lose data because of the collation on the column/table in sqlserver. (since the encoding is row specific in my case)

In this particular case I don't care much for issues regarding searching / sorting the data in the ui.

Another option might be to convert the incoming characters to a specific encoding (utf-8 for instance).

Since I don't feel I fully understand the problem domain (and yes I did read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) I'd like to know if there is a better way or maybe I'm concerned for nothing.

Comment: If I understand you correct - then I'm not sure you need to worry as long as you use nvarchar as your datatype. I have databases with Chinese, Russian, Danish, English etc in the same table using various collations